# App anime caracters

Tags: drawing, paint

I have a question
For example i'm a begginer java programmer 
And i want to built an game in android 
How i can get a anime caracters thats drawing for just my special ,thats mean new anime caracters for my special app

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but finding stock or custom artwork is not within [the scope of this site](http://crafts.stackexchange.com/tour).  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Umm... Osama, you are Propose your Idea at 2016, it may be better if you propose your Idea in Kick Starter or find Freelance Artist (if you are Indie/ Individual Developer). Propose your idea to supervisor (if you are working), and have an Final/ Group Project with Art & Design/ Animation/ Game Art student in your college or University and become a Portfolio (if you are a Student). Hope you Online next time, and listen to my advise... I'm trying to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Listen to John Vekelic's answer is to spend money, find a person and make your App look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you would be looking for a "freelance artist for hire".

In your case, you are "technically" a small business owner that needs concept designs and character development for a product you are trying to create.

You would create a design brief describing exactly what it is you are looking for. Any freelance artist who contacts you would request this document and, upon an agreed upon price, would begin the development work in creating the character based on the brief. The brief tells the artist what it is you need. The artist provides their aesthetic skills to bring to life the brief.

If you want to learn more about this process of hiring and working with illustrators and designers three good people to look up on YouTube are Children's Book Illustrator Will Terry,  Designer Feng Zhu of FDZSchool, and (Artists Pete Mohrbacher and Sam Flegal" of One Fantastic Week.

In you case, if cash is tight, you might want to go check out someplace where amature anime artists hang out at, such as local comic cons, gaming stores or school art programs. Find an artist who is looking to take part in a passion project like this. Go out and meet the artists, get to know them and their work. Let them know what you are looking for and what you are offering in exchange.

Partnerships are hard to create and maintain but they can be incredibly rewarding and fulfilling.

Good luck.

Comment: I know the community college near me has an anime club.  You might look for similar things if there's a college near you.

Comment: As a note, answering off topic questions doesn't discourage their asking...